# Write a header HTML tag markdown parser in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, markdown

The following is the best i could came up with;

```rb
def markdownparser(markdown)  
  if markdown.match("#")
    arr = markdown.split("")
    i = 0
    while arr[i] != " "
      if arr[i] == "#"
        i += 1
      end 
    end
    final = markdown[(i + 1)..(markdown.size + i)]
    return "<h" + i.to_s + ">" + final + "</h" + i.to_s + ">"
  else
    return markdown
  end
end

puts markdownparser(" smaller header")
```

The simple markdown parser function:

- takes in a single line of markdown
- translates it into the appropriate HTML header tag

**Headers** are designated by (1-6) **hashes** followed by a **space**, followed by **text**. The number of hashes determines the **header level** of the HTML output.

- Header content should only come *after the initial hashtag(s)* plus *a space character*.
- Invalid headers should just be *returned as the markdown* that was received without any translation.
- Spaces before and after both the header content and the hashtag(s) must be **ignored** in the resulting output

How can I reduce the time complexity further?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replace Explicit Loops with Standard Methods

You're doing a number of things in loops, so I'd avoid that unless you have a very specific use case for not using Ruby's optimized methods. There are builtin core or standard library methods for doing things like counting occurrences or replacing text, so I'd use those whenever possible. If speed really counts, I'd also opt for string interpolation rather than concatenation with [String#+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-2B) where each sub-expression creates a new intermediate string.

One way to implement this would be as follows:

```
md_str = <<~'EOF'
  # Header 1
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor  
  incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

  ## Header 2
  Etiam habebis sem dicantur magna mollis euismod.

  ####### Invalid Header with 7 "#" Characters
  ^^^^^^^ Too many characters to be valid.
EOF

# helper method to count header characters
def header_level str
  str&.count "#"
end

# replace markdown headers with html headers;
# escape hash in regex so it won't be treated as interpolation;
# block form required for proper handling of match variables
md_str.gsub!(/^(\#{1,6})\s+(.*)$/) { |_| "<h#{header_level $1}>#{$2}</h>" }

puts md_str
```

This leverages [String#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-count) to count the number of `#` characters in your string, rather than having to loop through it. [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) only calls #header_level on lines that start with a header character.

### Caveats

1. Obviously this doesn't handle "underlined" headers, but that wasn't part of your question.
2. Slurping files vs. line-at-a-time processing involves various trade-offs, but it can be hard to do complex parsing without context lines.
3. There's no substitute for [benchmarking](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) to test whether a given bit of code is really faster or not.
4. This approach doesn't do away with iteration, per se. It just offloads iteration to methods that run at C speed whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks Todd! Your solution worked for me and the testing site's IDE accepted after tweaking regex to meet all test cases